# Challenge in data from REST API using Azure Data Factory Synapse SQL as destination

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I have a pipeline with a Copy activity. The pipeline is working well with Azure SQL DB as Destination but when inserting to Synapse SQL DB , the pipeline fails with error code as below. I am auto creating the table.

Source: REST API

ErrorCode=UserErrorFailToReadFromRestResource,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=An error occurred while sending the request.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException,Message=An error occurred while sending the request.,Source=mscorlib,''Type=System.Net.WebException,Message=The remote server returned an error:

Answer (score 0):

As per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/develop-tables-overview) if you are copying to serverless pool it will not support. If not, I followed below procedure to copy data from rest Api to synapse dedicated SQL pool using below procedure:

I created a pipeline and run web activity to retrieve the details of Api as below:

[image]

it executed successfully without any error, I created linked service of Rest Api for source

[image]

Synapse Analytics linked service for sink:

[image]

I drag for each activity into the pipeline on success of web activity connecting to for each I entered range function for items expression as `@range(1,activity('restAPI').output.total_pages)`added copy activity to the for each activity, I created Rest Api dataset by using created linked service for source of copy activity and set get activity as request method created parameter rurl and added value as `?page=@{item()}` and entered relative rurl as `@dataset().rurl`

Source:

[image]

Created Synapse Analytics dataset by using created linked service for sink created table parameter and added `Apipage@{item()}` as dynamic content and kept the parameter as table name and enabled auto create table

[image]

I mapped according to my requirements:

[image]

I debug the pipeline and it executed successfully.

[image]

The data is copied successfully

[image]

I am having two pages that's why created 2 tables, its working fine for me check once again.